# Why is the physical keyboard not working in my Android app?

Tags: android

In my Android app, the soft keyboard is working properly, but the physical keyboard is **not** working. I could not find out the reason for this. Is it due to any coding mistake of my app, or my phone's issue?

Comment: Just your app, or all apps on your phone?

Comment: are you talking with the android emulator or in your device?

Comment: not emulator...i have tested my app in a phone...

Answer (score 0):

**if issue in emulator
then try this**

this is android AVD manager issue.

go Window -> ADV manager

then select Emulator and press Edit Button

then go Hardware section and press on New

after press new select property Keyboard support and press OK

and Set Value TRUE

**and is issue in phone then try this**

i would go to settings>language & keyboard... and check you keyboard settings... see if "shortcuts" is ON... Also, try clearing out "Learned Words"... that usually helps with any OS keyboard issue... :-)

if not, then get 1-click Cleaner from Market... its free... download... install.. run it... afterward run, turn phone off... remove battery... wait 2 min... insert battery and turn on... work now?

if not again... then you may need to do a factory reset... yes this will earse any data you put on the phone... except the SD card and SIM---these 2 will not be touched... but the internal memory will be wiped to factory settings---the way it looked on day 1 minute 1 of when you first got the phone...

if factory reset dont help the issue... then call tmobile to get a replacement... the g2 is OLD and i highly doubt your warranty is still active... you may need to upgrade or get a insurnace repalcement.... both needs money!.... good luck!
Source(s):
Sincerely,

Comment: The Hardware keyboard on his Phone is not working in his app. Not the emulator keyboard.

Comment: i will check it and let u know :)