# Flutter: keyboard not showing up with Textfield on Android

Tags: android, dart, flutter

As already mentioned in the title my keyboard does not show up when i click on TextField-Widgets. That is the same for every TextField across my application, but wasn't like that always. Unfortunately i don't use version control so I can't find out what's the error causing it.

I don't think it's some error in the code, my `flutter doctor` is fine also. I'll put my `pubspec.yaml` aswell as my `build.gradle` files, since I changed some of the stuff in them, maybe that helps. I'll also put one example of a textfield.

It happens on both Android devices I've tested, which are both on Android 9.0. I tried it on emulator with 8.1 Oreo and the keyboard seems to work on there.

one of my usage cases:

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.call_to_action),
      title: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Name", border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    ),
  ]),
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: whatever
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  google_sign_in: ^3.2.1

  googleapis: ^0.52.0

  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.5+2

  sqflite: ^0.12.2+1

  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1

  firebase_database: ^1.0.5

  barcode_scan: ^0.0.7

  numberpicker: ^0.1.7

  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.0.8

  image_picker: ^0.4.10

  chewie: ^0.8.0

  sticky_headers: ^0.1.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
      - assets/

  fonts:
    - family: Circular
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/circular-regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/circular-bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

App-Level `build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.whatever"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project-Level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting API 28 seems to have some problems with showing keyboard on physical devices
providing some links hope they help with your problem

[Github Flutter and API 28](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19644)

[Physical devices keyboard not popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067180/why-is-the-physical-keyboard-not-working-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 3):

Removing `enableFlutterDriverExtension()` from my `void main()` method, as noted [here in Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33693#issuecomment-497912052) solved this for me.  I'm still running against API 28 (no need to downgrade to 27)

Comment: As I am looking for Flutter Integration Testing, this line is mandatory. Is there any other alternative for same?

Comment: @VitthalBobade I believe this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15415#issuecomment-505621936) might be helpful if it is not too late.

Comment: Thanks @miloskarakas. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

changing my targetSdkVersion to 27 fixes my issue...nonono